# what is the difference between pytorch and python kernel in jupyter (or pyspark, tensorflow, XGBoost)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I noticed when I create a new Jupyter notebook, that I can choose different kernels that are all python based.

I understand when you would choose an R kernel vs a python kernel because you would be writing different code in those situations.

However, what I am really curious about is the difference between a pytorch kernel (or other python based package) and the python kernel.

Are there certain advantages of using the pytorch kernel for a pytorch project or would the python kernel work just as well?

[image: Possible kernels in Jupyter]